# AngularFireDatabase doesn't retrieve data synchronous

Tags: angular, typescript

My code returns a value in real time:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Usuario } from '../modelos/usuario';
import { UsuarioClass } from './../modelos/usuario-class.model';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UsuarioService {
    keyUsuario: string;
usuLogin: UsuarioClass;
constructor(
    private dbFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
}

getAuthenticateUser(
    strLogin: string,
    strPassword: string,
    intEstadoActivo: number) {
    var strKey : string = "";
    var objUsu : UsuarioClass = null;
    var query = this.dbFireDatabase.database.ref("TableUser").orderByKey();
    query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            objUsu = <UsuarioClass>childSnapshot.val();
            if ((objUsu.LOGIN.trim() == strLogin.trim()) &&
                (objUsu.PASSWORD.trim() == strPassword.trim()) &&
                (objUsu.ESTADO == intEstadoActivo)) {
                strKey = childSnapshot.key;
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    if ((strKey != "") && (strKey != null) && (strKey != undefined)) {
        xxxxx    //other step.
    }
    }

}
```

The code works well in the second call of the function, but in the first it does not. I try use the `async` and `await`, but I don't know the right way. In the fist call, strKey is empty, but in the second and later calls, strKey has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
var query = this.dbFireDatabase.database.ref("TableUser").orderByKey();
  query.once('value', function(snapshot) {

     /*Some code here*/

     return someResult;  
   }
  });                             
});
```

And then call this function like this:

```
this.yourService.getAuthenticateUser().then((result)=>{
     /* use the result*/
  }
```